# Plot not showing after plt.show(), gives no error 'and only shows : <Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>'

Tags: matplotlib, figure, geopandas

I'm trying to plot a geographical data using a shapefile and a dataframe,(following the instructions in this link:
https://towardsdatascience.com/lets-make-a-map-using-geopandas-pandas-and-matplotlib-to-make-a-chloropleth-map-dddc31c1983d) 
by merging them and then try to plot the geodata.

Here map_df is the shapefile read by geopandas, and df is the dataframe for the statistics about geography.

```
merged = map_df.set_index('NAME_3').join(df.set_index('City'))


variable = 'Rate'
vmin, vmax = 120, 220
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10, 6))

merged.plot(column=variable, cmap = 'Blues', linewidth=0.8, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

In the link there was 'edgecolor='0.8'' variable but it produced an RGBA error with my code and that's why I deleted that part. 
Now even when I use plt.show() it doesn't show the plot and only says:

```
 <Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>
```

What can I do about it? Thank you.

Comment: Does it work with the dataset presented in the link?

Comment: I tried it with the data in the link now and it shows the same result : Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>

Comment: Mhh, I'm running into [this problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262505/python-cant-read-shapefile) when trying the notebook from the link (seems not all needed files are in the repo); which means I cannot help further.

Answer (score 1):

If your matplotlib ax instance and merged.plot() are in the different code cells of the Jupyter Notebook with ax instance being generated first, consider putting the ax instance and merged.plot() in the same cell.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem using a jupyter notebook. The only thing that solved this for me was to create a new notebook. There it suddenly worked.